Merging multiple channels in Kotlin
Let's say I have two channels with same generic type. Is there an elegant way to join them and receive from both of them as from one channel? Example:
fun main() {
  val channel1 = ...
  val channel2 = ...
  val joined = join(channel1, channel2)
  val value = joined.receive() // waits on one of the channels to send something
}

The only possible solution I came up with was to launch another coroutines which constantly checks if any of the two has any value:
fun <T> join(channel1: ReceiveChannel<T>, channel2: ReceiveChannel<T>): ReceiveChannel<T> {
  val output = Channel<T>()
  launch {
    while (true) {
      val value1 = channel1.tryRecieve().getOrNull()
      if (value1 != null) {
        output.send(value1)
      }
      val value2 = channel2.tryRecieve().getOrNull()
      if (value2 != null) {
        output.send(value2)
      }
    }
  }
  return output
}

This is obviously not ideal, because we now have another coroutine, that runs without yielding.

what about using produce like suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584509/13404288
